# Почему Read/WriteProcessMemory не принимает адрес памяти из переменной?

Tags: c++, ram

У меня есть адрес, который мне нужно прочитать, но я столкнулся с проблемой, а именно:

```
    DWORD Adr = 0x284B103C830;
    int buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)Adr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    cout << buffer;
```

не работает ни при каких обстоятельствах, в то время как

```
int buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)0x284B103C830, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    cout << buffer;
```

работает исправно. Я сделал вывод что RPM и WPM по каким то причинам не могут получить адрес из переменной, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Почему `DWORD`? Он вроде 32-битный, и ваш адрес не влезает.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, долго не мог понять в чём проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас явно 64-разрядное приложение. Код

```
cout << sizeof(DWORD) << " " << sizeof(LPVOID) << endl;
```

выводит в этом случае

```
4 8
```

так что корректно поступить так — сразу записывать в переменную нужного размера:

```
LPVOID Adr = (LPVOID)0x284B103C830;
```